# How to prove "A->B,C then A->B and A->C" from Armstrong Axioms

Tags: primary-key, relational-theory, unique-constraint, database-theory, dependencies

I know that this is true but I don't understand how to prove it.

*The Problem:*

> Prove or disprove that if A->B,C, then  A->B and A->C

This [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123510/how-can-i-prove-disprove-if-a-%E2%86%A0-bc-and-a-%E2%86%92-b-then-a-%E2%86%92-c) is similar but it does not prove the relation using Armstrong's axioms.

Comment: Have you seen any other proof that uses Armstrong's axioms (an dhow they can be used)?

Comment: Why is the question suggested to be closed as off-topic?

Comment: @Lennart perhaps because it's too basic. I mean this kind of question / axioms are taught at university level but the proof needed is very basic. High school student level.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, perhaps, but if this question is too trivial then a fair amount of all other questions should be closed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just two steps: you can use reflexivity for `B C -> B` and then transitivity from `A -> B C` and the previous dependency. Analogous solution for the second case.